# How to 'cast' an object to a class inheritated by its superclass?

Tags: c++, casting, superclass

I have : (pseudocode )

```
A_GItem_rect::A_GItem_rect ( ) : QGraphicsRectItem () ,  A_GItem_base()
```

Ok, the `G_graphicsRcetItem` which, in turn, inherits  `QGRaphicsShapeitem`.

`G_item_base` has a `w_setPen()` method.

Inside it any of the next commands meaning a chrash :

```
((QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem *) this)->setPen(my_pen);
QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem * r = reinterpret_cast<QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem*>(this ) ;
```

How can I fix this. Thanks

Comment: You mentioned 7 different classes in your question: `A_GItem_rect`, `QGraphicsRectItem`, `A_GItem_base`, `G_graphicsRcetItem`, `QGRaphicsShapeitem`, `G_item_base`, `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem`. It really isn't clear which ones are relevant, and what the relationship between them is.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you do such a horrible thing?

When `A_GItem_rect` is a subclass of `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem` then you don't have to cas the `this` pointer to access the `setPen` method. A simple `this->setPen()` should suffice. If you explicitly want the `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem` version of the method you have to call it like this: `QAbstractGraphicsShapeItem::setPen()`.

`reinterpret_cast` is **bad**! Especially when you don't know what you are doing. If you really have to cast objects, try a `dynamic_cast` first.

Comment: But I need / want to have information about my pen inside A_Gitem_Base. Maybe I'm going to do something with this information before setting the pen. This is because I need access to setpen of QAbstracGrapchisShapeItem superclass (or base class) of A_Gitem_rect.

Comment: And... Inside A_Gitem_base I cannot access to the superclass... This is because I try to set the pen using the QAsbtractGrapchisShapeItem .....

Comment: You simply should not use this function there. Maybe you can try it with another inheritance scheme. E.G: let `A_Gitem_Base` be a subclass of `QAsbtractGrapchisShapeItem`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `dynamic_cast` instead when you move in class hierarchies, then check return value to see if you succeeded (`!=NULL`)

Comment: Yes, but that's almost certainly not the right solution for the OP's problem.